# Yii2 Kartik-V Typeahead Advanced Widget: How to store result in Mysql

Tags: mysql, json, yii2, typeahead.js

Tearing my hair out at this point, hopefully someone can help me out!

I am using the Kartik-V Typeahead Advanced widget with Yii2.

The plugin works, in that the functionality is working perfectly on the page, I search and the results appear in the auto complete list.

Unfortunately, **I am unable to store the result** in my database. I am seeing an issue on the following line:

```
->where([ 'name' => $model->name ])//This variable is returning null
```

Am I trying to store the data incorrectly? I have tried everything I can think of, but I am sure someone here will come up with something better!

**See below for the full code.**

My controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
$model = new Member();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $test = Test::find()
            ->where([ 'name' => $model->name ])//This variable is returning null
            ->one();

    $test->updateCounters(['times_used' => 1]);
}

return $this->render('index', [
    'model' => $model,
]);

}

/*************
* Initial prefetch of results
*************/
public function actionPrefetchlist() {
$query = new Query;

$query->select('name')
      ->from('test_table')
      ->limit(10)
      ->orderBy('times_used');
$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
$out = [];
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $out[] = ['value' => $d['name']];
}
echo Json::encode($out);
}

/*************
* Remote results
*************/
public function actionRemotelist() {
$query = new Query;

$query->select('name')
      ->from('test_table')
      ->where('name LIKE "%' . $q .'%"')
      ->limit(10)
      ->orderBy('times_used');
$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
$out = [];
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $out[] = ['value' => $d['name']];
}
echo Json::encode($out);
}
```

The view file:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->label(false)->widget(Typeahead::classname(), [
   'name' => 'name',
   'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
   'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
   'dataset' => [
   [
        'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
        'display' => 'value',
        'prefetch' => Url::to(['prefetchlist']),
        'remote' => [
            'url' => Url::to(['remotelist']) . '?q=%QUERY',
            'wildcard' => '%QUERY'
        ]
   ]
   ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! BTW, you forgot the $q into the actionRemoteList parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was a massive rookie error.

If anyone else stumbles upon something similar, I removed the attribute `name` from the model's "rules()"

I need an integer in the database but I wanted users to enter in a string (I would then convert it in the controller). Removing it from the rule broke everything.

Hopefully this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

you ask here for a new model:

```
$model = new Member();
```

so you get a empty model
so the `$model->name` is empty
if you set the model `$model->name='test';`
than it will be filled so, fill the model first

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I ended up realising I had removed the attribute from the model rules(). As for your response, you need to create the $model variable with the model it is associated with, then you '$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())' to assign the values. Thanks though :)